# Clarification on permissions with GID & UID in UNIX

Tags: permissions, files, group

If Test1 & Test2 are users, then

```
Test1 : UID : 501, GID :501, groups=501,100
Test2 : UID : 502, GID :502, groups=502,100
```

What will be the correct option from below and explain how?

- Test1 can't access any file from Test2 because both are having different GID
- Test1 and Test 2 can access each others files because both are having 100 as group

Comment: Neither is correct and I would consider changing schools if I got these kind of homework question.

Answer (score 2):

Each file has an owner and group. If Test1 creates a file owned by the 100 group, Test2 can access it. So, neither option is true - access to files depends on file permissions, not their creators's groups.

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions can be based on user and group (there are few other things also), but this has nothing to do with this two questions.

So if you want two users which are in the same group to access the same directory/file... then you should need to set adequate ownership and permissions, put them into the same group maybe, etc...

Do you have some concrete example?

There are also concepts like suid, guid, sticky-bit...